# Mail4ME Api works on emulator but not on the phone

Tags: java, java-me, smtp, nokia, java-wireless-toolkit

I am developing a j2me application that sends emails. This is the code I wrote:

```
public class SendMail extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {

    SmtpClient smtpClient = null;
    Form form=null;
    Command cmdSend=null;
    Command cmdExit=null;

    protected void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {
        form = new Form("Send Email");
        cmdSend = new Command("Send", Command.OK, 0);
        cmdExit = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 0);
        form.addCommand(cmdExit);
        form.addCommand(cmdSend);
        form.setCommandListener(this);
        Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(form);
    }

    protected void pauseApp() {
    }

    protected void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) throws MIDletStateChangeException {
        notifyDestroyed();
    }

    public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
        if (d == form) {
            if (c == cmdSend) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Message message = new Message("****@gmx.com", "****@live.com", "Test my j2me app");
                            message.addBodyLine("Hi this is a test email by me");
                            smtpClient = new SmtpClient("http://127.0.0.1/");
                            smtpClient.open("mail.gmx.com", 587, false, "****@gmx.com", "myPassword");
                            smtpClient.sendMessage(message);
                            smtpClient.close();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                            form.append(ex.getMessage()+ "*1*");
                        } catch (MailException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                            form.append(ex.getMessage() + "*2*");
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            } else if (c == cmdExit) {
                try {
                    destroyApp(true);
                } catch (MIDletStateChangeException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this code using WTK 2.5.2_01 and it work perfect and I received the email on my live account, but when deploying the app in my Nokia N70 it doesn't work, and shows this exception:

`connection closed by peer *1*`

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd test with `"IOE: [" + ex + "]"` appended to form instead of  `ex.getMessage() + *1*` - in my experience this way typically has been producing more informative error messages